# How to print certain specific character from row to column?

Tags: python, string, csv, input, text

I have an input file that contains data in the same format repeatedly across 5 rows. I need to format this data into one row (CSV file) and have only few fields relevant to me. How do i achieve the mentioned output with the input file provided.

Note - I'm very new to learning any language and haven't reached to this depth of details yet to write my own. I have already written the code where i'm importing the input file, reaching to a specif word and then printing the rest of the data(this is where i need help as i don't need all the information in the input as using space is delimiter is not giving the output in correct columns). I have also written the code to write the output in a csv file.

Note 2 - I'm very to this forum as well and kindly excuse me in case i have made any posting in posting my query.

Input -
[Input File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0DB7.png)

Output -
[Output File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HLjN.png)

```
import itertools, csv
```

Comment: Hi! Would you like to provide the solutions you've made so far?

Comment: Hi Alessandro, Please find the progress so far in the actual question, but it not giving desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You should read in the file and parse it manually, then use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to write it to a `.csv` file:

```py
import re

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# divide on whitespace characters, but not single spaces
lines = [re.split("\s\s+", line) for line in lines]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for line in lines:
        writer.writerow(lines)
```

But this will include every piece of data. You can iterate through `lines` and remove the fields you don't want to keep. So before you do the csv writing, you could do:

```py
def filter_line(line):
    # see how the input file was parsed
    print(line)
    # for example, only keep the first 2 columns
    return [line[0], line[1]]

lines = [filter_line(line) for line in lines]
```

Comment: Thank you dogman288 for your quick reply, In the input file in line 3 we have "LIVING TOGETHER" and in line 8 we have only "LIVING". If we use "space" as delimiter, LIVING and TOGETHER gets printed in 2 columns but i want both of them in one column.

Comment: I see, it's a little difficult to tell without the text of your input and output (in the future you should upload text instead of images). For complex splitting like you need (i.e. split on whitespace, but not on single spaces, you should use regex. See the updated answer.